# autopep8 failing with "failed to create process."

Tags: python-3.x

Running on windows with Python 3.3.5

All follows attempts:

- autopep8
- autopep8 test.py
- autopep8 --in-place test.py

produced:

failed to create process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373265/pip-easy-install-failure-failed-to-create-process).

Did you rename the python folder?  Perhaps try reinstalling autopep8.

Comment: You are right, I moved some network installation and that was the cause. Thank you.