# Pyinstaller not working Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm trying to use Pyinstaller on a python file

```
Pyinstaller.exe --onefile E:\Ava-Bot\AVA-Bot.py
```

But there is an error

```
failed to create process.
```

Note: I'm working on Windows 8.1

Comment: Sorry forgot to add this, it is Windows 8.1

Comment: @magic-sudo it's not a game :3

Comment: Take a look at this and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373265/pip-easy-install-failure-failed-to-create-process

Comment: I looked at it before asking :(
doesn't help

Comment: I know this doesn't really solve the problem, but if worse comes to worse you could try the web installer or manual zip installation. https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-351/

Comment: thanks for help, I already solved the problem :), just easy_install it instead if pip install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was in pyinstaller installing

I was installing it by `pip install`it doesn't work

tried to `easy_install` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I used `easy_install pyinstaller` in the script folder under python. Something happened because now when I run `pyinstaller` it showes something else then the typical "the program does not exist".

Then I run this in command window:

```
pyinstaller test.py
```

It showed an error at the end, something like `pypiwin32=322`. I had to install that with pip too, but I can't recall now how I did it. But I googled it. It had to be the 322 witch was hard to get by.

Then I had to install, it did not work with latest version:

```
pip install altgraph==0.15
```

Even tough I am a newbie, and I spend 2 hours on this, I thought I share. My basic strategy was to read the errors at the end, and google the error message. Then it worked.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, I did not think anyone would look at it. I am from Sweden, witch mean I understand much more than I can express, witch is bad. So tanks a lot again for correcting 100 mistakes.