# PIP Failed to create process

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

Python Version 2.7
On windows 10 64bits

```
pip install <whatever>
```

command not working.

```
C:\new_software\Python27\Scripts>python -m ensurepip
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\new_software\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools-28.8.0-py2.7.egg
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\new_software\python27\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg

C:\new_software\Python27\Scripts>python -m ensurepip --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in c:\new_software\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools-28.8.0-py2.7.egg
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\new_software\python27\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg

C:\new_software\Python27\Scripts>pip install wheel
failed to create process.

C:\new_software\Python27\Scripts>python -m install pip install pip
C:\new_software\Python27\python.exe: No module named install
```

I have python 3.x and 2.7; in 3.x pip works fine; only in 2.7 it aint.

Based on reading articles online: I have completed:

1.environment variable set up.
2.python VC++ installed

Comment: The latest Python 2.7 comes with pip. Run the installer again, and you'll see the option to select it

Comment: The last command `python -m install pip install pip` should be `python -m pip install pip`

Comment: Did you mean to run `python -m pip install -U pip`? `python -m install` is not correct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip/easy\_install failure: failed to create process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373265/pip-easy-install-failure-failed-to-create-process)

Comment: Thank you all for your response. I read the link shared by @cricket_007. Solution: Update all .py files [firstline] inside /Scripts folder with current path of Python Home. You will notice it will be pointing to an older location. Then try running pip command from new CMD prompt, should work fine.

Comment: You are welcome to answer your own question below rather than leave it as a comment

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your response. *I read the link shared by @cricket_007*. 
**Solution:** 
Update all .py files [firstline] inside /Scripts folder with current path of Python Home. You will notice it will be pointing to an older location. 
Then try running pip command from new CMD prompt, should work fine.