# Q: Command Line says "Failed to created process" when I try to pip install a package

Tags: python, pip

5 and having no problems but I'm on windows 10 and I read online that I can't edit the system variables to add to the path to run programs from command line easily. I decided to uninstall python 3.5 and install python 3.8.2, which is the latest version, so that I could click on the “add to path” option.

The install went okays, but when I tried to go to the command prompt and install third party packages using pip, the command prompt kept saying "failed to create process"

I tried repairing the installations, trying different versions but the same thing kept happening.

Is there a fix for this? Help...

Thanks

```
C:\\WINDOWS\\system32>pip install pyperclip

failed to create process.


C:\\WINDOWS\\system32>
```

Comment: have you tried `python -m pip install`?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the 64 bit python 3.8 dev module on the microsoft store, as the install from python webpage was most likely 32bit.

here is the link: https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9MSSZTT1N39L

```
C:\Users\Ben Woo>pip install pyperclip
Collecting pyperclip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f6/5b/55866e1cde0f86f5eec59dab5de8a66628cb0d53da74b8dbc15ad8dabda3/pyperclip-1.8.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyperclip
  Running setup.py install for pyperclip ... done
Successfully installed pyperclip-1.8.0
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Users\Ben Woo>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I installed the 64 bit one from the python website. I installed the wrong one at first and then uninstalled it and reinstalled the 64 bit but the same thing happens. I tried to install the one thru the link to the microsoft store and same issue happens. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Actually seem like there is answer here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373265/pip-easy-install-failure-failed-to-create-process)

Comment: @BenWoo While it might be recommended to use the 64 bit version, why do you think that it is the only one working and why do you think that it needs to be installed from the microsoft store? The 32 bit version from the python website should work just as fine as the 64 bit version on a 64 bit system