# When I run pipwin, I get "failed to create process." This happens no matter what pipwin command I try, and pipwin is already installed

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I already did pip install pipwin with no issues. This happens whenever I run pipwin:

```
    PS C:\Users\Family PC\Documents\Charlie1\Python>pipwin install pyaudio
    failed to create process.
    PS C:\Users\Family PC\Documents\Charlie1\Python> pipwin list
    failed to create process.
    PS C:\Users\Family PC\Documents\Charlie1\Python> pipwin refresh
    failed to create process.
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. I looked everywhere for solutions, but I can't find any.

*Note: I am very new to python!*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip/easy\_install failure: failed to create process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373265/pip-easy-install-failure-failed-to-create-process)

Comment: @AMC, no all the answers there were for issues with pip itself. I tried the suggestions anyway, but nothing happened.

Comment: Ah damn, I'll take another look then. While it's not exactly a solution to this particular problem, there is a [Conda package for Pyaudio](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pyaudio), if you're open to using that.

Comment: I downloaded Anaconda, but I'm not sure how to use it in Visual Studio Code

Comment: Take a look at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments.

Comment: I followed all the steps, but when I run conda commands it gives me an error that says that conda isn't recognized. I think the best option is to see if the pipwin issue can be solved first, because using anaconda just causes more problems for me that I don't have the knowledge to fix

Comment: That’s a common problem, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597662/conda-command-is-not-recognized-on-windows-10. I hope we find a fix for the pipwin issue!